# python program to find the primes in the fibonacci sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

hello all sorry to be a pain with this one. I need help with this problem for my coding class, and I can't quite figure out where to go from here.

Write a function my_n_fib_primes(n) where theoutput fib_primes is a list of the first nnumbers that are both a Fibonacci number and a prime.  Note that 1 is not prime.Test using n = 9.

the above is what I am supposed to do and so far I have this.

```
def my_n_fib_primes(n):
    n0=0
    n1=1
    fib_primes = []
    count = 0
    while count < n:
        count += 1
        nth = n0 + n1
        n0 = n1
        n1 = nth
        fib_primes.append(n0)
    return fib_primes
my_n_fib_primes(9)
```

I know I haven't made any real attempt for implementing the primes yet. I just can't quite figure out a way to implement it and only make the count go up when the number is prime.

I also already have a code for finding prime numbers that returns the number 1 if the number is prime and 0 if it isn't. that code is this.

```
def my_is_prime(n):
    out = 1
    if n > 1:
        for i in range(2,n//2):
            if (n % i) == 0:
                out = 0
    else:
        out = 1
    return out
```

can someone point me in the right direction? thank you.

Comment: It's preferable to use `True` and `False` for boolean values, not `1` and `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Call the prime checker in the loop before adding the number to the list.

```
def my_n_fib_primes(n):
    n0=0
    n1=1
    fib_primes = []
    while len(fib_primes) < n:
        nth = n0 + n1
        n0 = n1
        n1 = nth
        if my_is_prime(n0):
            fib_primes.append(n0)
    return fib_primes
```

There's no need for the `count` variable, just use the length of the result list.